# PowerShell Copy on a mapped or UNC Drive (SQL Server Job Agent)

Tags: sql-server, powershell

What am I doing wrong?

As a step in a Job I am trying to overwrite file by copying the drive is mapped, but I am using unc path just in case.

In PowerShell this works in the command line interface.

> Copy \V240\folder\foo.txt \V240\folder\bar.txt

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4qOW.png)

When I put it in a Job Agent in SQL Server with the PowerShell option it says successfully completed but the file has not been copied.

Comment: Does it work in POSH from the SQL server machine or from your desktop?  It's possible the SQL machine doesn't have access to that path and/or it's not mapped.

Comment: I have tried it on the server and on my desktop and in Powershell ISE all work.

Comment: The server has the path mapped and I can access file through explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Powershell SQL Agent job step starts Powershell sqlps host in the SQL Server provider. I would try setting location (cd) to the filesystem provider before copying

```
set-location c:\
Copy \V240\folder\foo.txt \V240\folder\bar.txt
```